# Why it's not allowed to print the content of PChar as a pointer

Tags: pointers, delphi, pchar

I have the following program.

```
var a: PChar := PChar('abc');
ShowMessage(Format('%p - %p', [@a, a]));
```

When I run it, I got this error:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message 'Format '%p - %p' invalid or incompatible with argument'.

The problem is that `a` can't be formatted as `%p`. But as I understand, PChar is defined as `^Char`. So a PChar is essentially a pointer to Char. It's a pointer. Why can't format it as `%p`? The following code works without any issue:

```
var c: Char := 'x';
var a := @c;

Format('%p - %p', [@a, a]);   // 0019F364 - 0019F36A
```

Comment: Yes it's a pointer, but it's more than that. It's a pointer to null terminated array of char. Just cast it `Pointer(a)`

Comment: I believe the reason it works is that "@c" is of type POINTER and not of type PChar (do you have "Typed @ operator" compiler setting enabled? If not, @<anything> is of type POINTER). Try with "var a : PChar = @c;" instead, where you explicitly set the variable to type PChar, or try inserting a {$T+} compiler option at the top of your UNIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of `Format()` is an `array of const` (essentially, an array of [`TVarRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec)).  A typed `PChar` pointer is stored in the `TVarRec.VPChar` field (`TVarRec.VType=vtPChar`), whereas untyped pointers are stored in the `TVarRec.VPointer` field (`TVarRec.VType=vtPointer`).  The `%p` specifier is supported only for the `VPointer` field.  Only the `%s` specifier is supported for the `VPChar` field.

So, you will have to type-cast `PChar` to `Pointer` if you want to use `%p`.

I have filed a report with Embarcadero about this:

[RSP-37775: Update SysUtils.Format() to allow %p for all types of pointers](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37775)